# How can I solve this error to call data frame in R?

Tags: r, rstudio, markdown

So when I run R and try to read a file, it gives me an error like this
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmESI.jpg)

But I definitely have my file in my directory. As I can tell below photo.

[working directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voeCS.jpg)

How can I solve this problem??

Comment: your screenshot does not show a rubber.csv

Comment: You say `rubber.csv` but you have `rubber.df.txt.gz`

Comment: I think you were misguided but I edited my answer and I think it will actually help now.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely don't have that file in your directory as I can tell from your photo.

However it seems you don't understand what you're looking at. It seems you want to use the rubber.df dataset from the R330 package which you can load using `data(rubber.df)` and then use by calling rubber.df